# Grails dependency injection with package private classes

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Using Grails (3.x) I would like to make implementations unavailable for users of a certain plugin. Functionality provided with the plugin is made avaible with depenency injection/inversion of control.
I therefore define a public interface and a package private implementation of this interface.
Secondly I would like to register the bean through `resources.groovy` however this needs importing the class to use - and it's package private.

In Spring i would annotate the class itself with "@Service" making it available through dependency injection (and thus references to package private classes is avoided).

How would one overcome this in Grails (3)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is possible to use spring annotations: [Spring - The foundation for grails](http://spring.io/blog/2010/06/08/spring-the-foundation-for-grails/)